# ReflectionException - Class `AdminUsersController` does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-routing

I am using `laravel 4.2`. My `AdminUsersController` looks like that:

```
<?php

class AdminUsersController extends AdminController {


    /**
     * User Model
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Role Model
     * @var Role
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * Permission Model
     * @var Permission
     */
    protected $permission;

    /**
     * Inject the models.
     * @param User $user
     * @param Role $role
     * @param Permission $permission
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Role $role, Permission $permission)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->role = $role;
        $this->permission = $permission;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        // Title
        $title = Lang::get('admin/users/title.user_management');

        // Grab all the users
        $users = $this->user;

        // Show the page
        return View::make('admin/users/index', compact('users', 'title'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getCreate()
    {
        // All roles
        $roles = $this->role->all();

        // Get all the available permissions
        $permissions = $this->permission->all();

        // Selected groups
        $selectedRoles = Input::old('roles', array());

        // Selected permissions
        $selectedPermissions = Input::old('permissions', array());

        // Title
        $title = Lang::get('admin/users/title.create_a_new_user');

        // Mode
        $mode = 'create';

        // Show the page
        return View::make('admin/users/create_edit', compact('roles', 'permissions', 'selectedRoles', 'selectedPermissions', 'title', 'mode'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postCreate()
    {
        $this->user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
        $this->user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
        $this->user->password = Input::get( 'password' );

        // The password confirmation will be removed from model
        // before saving. This field will be used in Ardent's
        // auto validation.
        $this->user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );
        $this->user->confirmed = Input::get( 'confirm' );

        // Permissions are currently tied to roles. Can't do this yet.
        //$user->permissions = $user->roles()->preparePermissionsForSave(Input::get( 'permissions' ));

        // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
        $this->user->save();

        if ( $this->user->id )
        {
            // Save roles. Handles updating.
            $this->user->saveRoles(Input::get( 'roles' ));

            // Redirect to the new user page
            return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $this->user->id . '/edit')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.create.success'));
        }
        else
        {
            // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
            $error = $this->user->errors()->all();

            return Redirect::to('admin/users/create')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with( 'error', $error );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getShow($user)
    {
        // redirect to the frontend
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getEdit($user)
    {
        if ( $user->id )
        {
            $roles = $this->role->all();
            $permissions = $this->permission->all();

            // Title
            $title = Lang::get('admin/users/title.user_update');
            // mode
            $mode = 'edit';

            return View::make('admin/users/create_edit', compact('user', 'roles', 'permissions', 'title', 'mode'));
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.does_not_exist'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postEdit($user)
    {
        // Validate the inputs
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $user->getUpdateRules());


        if ($validator->passes())
        {
            $oldUser = clone $user;
            $user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
            $user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
            $user->confirmed = Input::get( 'confirm' );

            $password = Input::get( 'password' );
            $passwordConfirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );

            if(!empty($password)) {
                if($password === $passwordConfirmation) {
                    $user->password = $password;
                    // The password confirmation will be removed from model
                    // before saving. This field will be used in Ardent's
                    // auto validation.
                    $user->password_confirmation = $passwordConfirmation;
                } else {
                    // Redirect to the new user page
                    return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.password_does_not_match'));
                }
            } else {
                unset($user->password);
                unset($user->password_confirmation);
            }

            if($user->confirmed == null) {
                $user->confirmed = $oldUser->confirmed;
            }

            $user->prepareRules($oldUser, $user);

            // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
            $user->amend();

            // Save roles. Handles updating.
            $user->saveRoles(Input::get( 'roles' ));
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.edit.error'));
        }

        // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
        $error = $user->errors()->all();

        if(empty($error)) {
            // Redirect to the new user page
            return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.edit.success'));
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('admin/users/' . $user->id . '/edit')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.edit.error'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove user page.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getDelete($user)
    {
        // Title
        $title = Lang::get('admin/users/title.user_delete');

        // Show the page
        return View::make('admin/users/delete', compact('user', 'title'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified user from storage.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postDelete($user)
    {
        // Check if we are not trying to delete ourselves
        if ($user->id === Confide::user()->id)
        {
            // Redirect to the user management page
            return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.delete.impossible'));
        }

        AssignedRoles::where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();

        $id = $user->id;
        $user->delete();

        // Was the comment post deleted?
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ( empty($user) )
        {
            // TODO needs to delete all of that user's content
            return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('success', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.delete.success'));
        }
        else
        {
            // There was a problem deleting the user
            return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/users/messages.delete.error'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a list of all the users formatted for Datatables.
     *
     * @return Datatables JSON
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $users = User::leftjoin('assigned_roles', 'assigned_roles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->leftjoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'assigned_roles.role_id')
                    ->select(array('users.id', 'users.username','users.email', 'roles.name as rolename', 'users.confirmed', 'users.created_at'));

        return Datatables::of($users)
        // ->edit_column('created_at','{{{ Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon::createFromFormat(\'Y-m-d H\', $test)) }}}')

        ->edit_column('confirmed','@if($confirmed)
                            Yes
                        @else
                            No
                        @endif')

        ->add_column('actions', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-default">{{{ Lang::get(\'button.edit\') }}}</a>
                                @if($username == \'admin\')
                                @else
                                    <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-danger">{{{ Lang::get(\'button.delete\') }}}</a>
                                @endif
            ')

        ->remove_column('id')

        ->make();
    }
}
```

My routes look like that:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function()
// {
//  return View::make('hello');
// });
//

// // Confide routes
// Route::get('users/create', 'UsersController@create');
// Route::post('users', 'UsersController@store');
// Route::get('users/login', 'UsersController@login');
// Route::post('users/login', 'UsersController@doLogin');
// Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', 'UsersController@confirm');
// Route::get('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@forgotPassword');
// Route::post('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@doForgotPassword');
// Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', 'UsersController@resetPassword');
// Route::post('users/reset_password', 'UsersController@doResetPassword');
// Route::get('users/logout', 'UsersController@logout');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route constraint patterns
 *  ------------------------------------------
*/
Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('role', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('token', '[0-9a-z]+');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Admin Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
*/
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    # User Management
    Route::get('users/{user}/show', 'AdminUsersController@getShow');
    Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@getEdit');
    Route::post('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@postEdit');
    Route::get('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@getDelete');
    Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

    # User Role Management
    Route::get('roles/{role}/show', 'AdminRolesController@getShow');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@getEdit');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@postEdit');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@getDelete');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
});


/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Frontend Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
*/

// User reset routes
Route::get('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset');
// User password reset
Route::post('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@postReset');
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/{user}/edit', 'UserController@postEdit');

//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

# User RESTful Routes (Login, Logout, Register, etc)
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

//:: Application Routes ::

# Filter for detect language
Route::when('contact-us','detectLang');

# Contact Us Static Page
Route::get('contact-us', function()
{
    // Return about us page
    return View::make('site/contact-us');
});

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang','uses' => 'UserController@postLogin'));
```

My file path looks like that:

[image]

However, I get the following exception when I open the public folder of my application:

```
ReflectionException thrown with message "Class AdminUsersController does not exist"

Stacktrace:
#22 ReflectionException in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php:28
#21 ReflectionClass:__construct in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php:28
#20 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector:getRoutable in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:269
#19 Illuminate\Routing\Router:controller in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:211
#18 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade:__callStatic in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\app\routes.php:59
#17 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route:controller in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\app\routes.php:59
#16 {closure} in <#unknown>:0
#15 call_user_func in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:691
#14 Illuminate\Routing\Router:group in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:211
#13 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade:__callStatic in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\app\routes.php:71
#12 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route:group in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\app\routes.php:71
#11 require in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php:269
#10 {closure} in <#unknown>:0
#9 call_user_func in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:830
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:fireAppCallbacks in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:604
#7 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:bootApplication in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:587
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:boot in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:743
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:641
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-application\public\index.php:49
```

Any suggestions why the controller cannot be found? I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should add to your `composer.json` into `autoload` -> `classmap` section `admin` and `user` directories so it should look like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/controllers/admin",
        "app/controllers/user"
    ]
},
```

and run `composer dump-autoload` after saving file